# Diaplaying SSMS standard report in your web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

SSMS 2005 & 2008 comes with inbuilt standard reports.

How can we display these standard reports inside a asp.net web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download these reports as RDL files here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317002859/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/managingsql/archive/2006/08/30/ssms-reports-3.aspx)

Deploy them to SSRS and put standard ReportViewer control on your page to display a report.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of deploying to SSRS how can we use this as Local Report?

Comment: You can use ReportViewer control in "Local" mode, which does not require SSRS. But it has limitations (no parameter prompting, no sql queries) and may require additional programming to make things work.

Comment: Does this solution still apply to newer versions (sql server & ssms 2016)? If so, where are the rdl’s found?